# Nested Firestore queries not returning results to primary query

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've got two Firestore collections, /projects and /tasks. The /tasks collection contains a reference field to a id field in the /projects collection. In typescript I've extended my the task class with a projectname member. So when querying the /tasks collection I need to return the projectname as well.

My current code is using valueChanges(), my first attempt was made using snapshotChanges().

Currently my code looks like this:

```js
this.xtasks = this.tasksCollection.valueChanges().pipe(
      map(values => values.map(data => {
          return {
              created: data.created,
              createdby: data.createdby,
              description: data.description,
              due: data.due,
              lastmodified: data.lastmodified,
              lastmodifiedby: data.lastmodifiedby,
              project: data.project, // i.e. /projects/<guid>
              sort: data.sort,
              state: data.state,
              title: data.title,
              uid: data.uid,
              projectname: this.projectService.getProjectStringField(data.project.replace('/projects/', ''), 'name') // supposed to retrive name of a project by project guid
            };
        })
      )
    );
```

But when the pipe returns the result the projectname is empty. I've tried looking into Promise but I'm not able to get it to return a value for projectname.

In the snippet all /tasks field are represented in the data object but I want to fetch the project name as well.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot of a document you expect to show up.

Comment: is `data.project` a document reference or a string?  what is getProjectStringField()?

Comment: yes, data.project is a document reference and is a string i.e. "/projects/<guid>" where <guid> is a unique document key. getProjectStringField() (terriable abbriviation I know) method is a method for retrieving the value of project name.